# How to store strings for html page in separate file?

Tags: html, variables

First time making a webpage in html. I have an assignment to format a bunch of text using appropriate html tags. No problem. But I would like to clean up my code by storing the paragraphs in a separate file. I have been searching for hours and cannot find anything.

Bottom line what I want to do:

have a file: strings.{html/xml/php/js}

and access variables from that file in my page index.html doing something like this:

```
<p>$someVarName</p>
```

Comment: That's not possible to do using plain HTML.

Comment: HTML is a markup language. You can do it with a language like PHP or JS.

Comment: *HTML* and *variables* are not two words that can be used in the same sentence..

Comment: Nature of the beast unless you use php or something else

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bit of a strange 'optimization', one that is not usually made, at least as far as I understand the question.

What you can do is have a JavaScript file e.g. script.js, and reference it in your index.html file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

In script.js you can insert custom HTML as such:

```
document.getElementById('tag-id').innerHTML = '<p>some text</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the page load time of a website in the browser usually one tries to deliver one HTML file per page and one compact CSS/JS/image/SVG file for the whole website. All files are usually aggregated server side from multiple resources as you like to do.
Here are some common ways to enrich HTML pages and their creation process:

**Using an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)** you can let the browser import and display another page using a single HTML tag but this is not recommended because it complicates layouting and a content's URL is not visible to the user in the browser's address bar.

**Using [PHP](http://php.net/)** you could have an index.php with the contents of your index.html plus some PHP snippets printing variables from an included variables.php. PHP requires server side execution which is typically implemented using [Apache2 webserver](http://httpd.apache.org/). A PHP script, index.php, would be executed each request / each time a user accesses the page.

index.php

```
<html>
    <?php require_once 'variables.php'; ?>
    ...
    <?php print $property1; ?>
    <?php print $property2; ?>
</html>
```

variables.php

```
<?php
    $property1 = 'value 1';
    $property2 = 'value 2';
?>
```

**Using [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)** you can transform the HTML as XML. This requires the HTML formatted as well-formed XML. XSLT can be executed both client and server side. XSLT 1 is limited but supported by major modern browsers. XSLT 2 is not supported by most browsers but often executed on the server side or rather offline to generate aggregated static html pages from XML/HTML with e.g. [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml). On the downside XSLT may be more difficult to start with than PHP.

**Using JavaScript (JS)** you can also let the browser load additional documents into a currently displayed document. This is also known as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and can be done with e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). With JS you can create interactive web pages and most modern websites make use of it.
BUT: Loading contents with JS on the client side limits the ability of search engines to index your content (bots usually do not execute JS). You should only use this method if your contents should not be crawled by bots or if you provide an alternative.

Of course, there is also a plethora of other template/programming languages that offer server side solutions for your problem like Java, Python and Ruby and their specialized frameworks.

Additionally you should check out one of the [many existing PHP CMS](http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=all) (server side HTML page generator with UI to edit content).